# Serve node api data to client side js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm using [request](https://github.com/request/request) to make a api call, and return some data to my app.
I'm able to receive the data in the body response of my code

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    request('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/apikey/37.8267,-122.4233', function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('error:', error); 
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
      console.log('body:', body); 
    });
}).listen(3000);

console.log('Server is up and running');
```

The api call is made then i hit my index file at / - so far, so good

However i want to send the body response, with my data, to a react js file, so i can use the data to serve to the client.
I can't seem to find any help on how to serve data to another javascript file.

Comment: Can you post the code to show how you are making the GET request in your react js file?

Comment: The problem is that i don't know how i should do it, but i guess i would use axios, or jQuery to make a call. But should i just make a request to the file above?

Comment: I would make a new `app.get` route specifically for returning the data you receive from the api.darksky.net request, to separate it from your homepage route returning index.html. In that, you can `return res.json(body)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should serve your index in one path, and the darksky request in another one.

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.get('/api/forecast, function(req, res) {
    request('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/apikey/37.8267,-122.4233', function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); 
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
        console.log('body:', body);
        res.json(body);
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server is up and running');
```

and on the client side use an ajax request to your server in order to get the body, something like this:

```
return $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/api/forecast')
      .then(function(data) {
        this.setState({ forecast: data.results });
      });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This seems like something i'm looking for. I'll try it out :) Thanks!

Comment: jQuery doesn't seem to be happy though: GET http://localhost:3000/api/forecast net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED jquery.min.js:4

Comment: @c-poulsen hey would you like to try Axios library? It supports promises and you can use it on both client and server side. I replaced all my `request` library methods with Axios https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: The error is on the client side. The API call from the server returns data, but when i call my own server i get the error above. I can try axios on the client side though

Comment: Or i could also just try to call the server using the proper port :D

Comment: it was not the 3000?

Comment: I changed it in my own code, and turned my brain off when i used your example